# Can "Stealth Tower" copy your opponent's bases?

Tags: star-realms

If I play a "Stealth Tower" base on my turn, can it copy a base that my opponent still has in play? The text says any base in play, but are your opponents bases considered in play during your turn?

[image]

Bonus question: If I destroy the base that "Stealth Tower" is coping, does it affect "Stealth Tower" or is it still a copy until end of turn?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your opponents bases are `In Play` so `Stealth Tower` can copy them too.

After `Stealth Tower` copies a base, it remains a copy of that base regardless of what happens to the original (destroyed or returned to hand, etc).

This relies on an understanding of what "In Play" means in the context of this game.

> A Player Turn consists of three phases: Main, Discard and Draw.
>
> **1) Main Phase**
>
> At any time during your Main Phase you may perform any of the
>   following actions, in any order you wish.
>
> - **Play cards from your hand**
> - Use the Primary Abilities of in-play Bases
> - Use the Ally/Scrap abilities of in-play Ships and Bases
> - Use Trade to acquire new cards from the Trade Row
> - Use Combat to attack an opponent and/or their Bases
>
> **Playing Cards**: There is no cost to play a card, simply place it `in-play` (face-up on the table in front of you [the active player]).
>   There are two types of cards you can have in your deck: Ships and
>   Bases.
>
> Bases: *Unlike Ships, Bases are not discarded at the end of the turn.
>   Instead, they remain `in-play` until they are destroyed or scrapped.*
>
> **2) Discard Phase**
>
> - Lose any Trade remaining in your Trade Pool
> - Lose any Combat remaining in your Combat Pool
> - **Put all `in-play` Ships into your Discard Pile [and leave all Bases in-play]**
> - Put any cards left in your hand into your Discard Pile
>
> **3) Draw Phase**
>
> Draw five cards, then your turn ends

In the Main Phase the first action says you can play cards from your hand. Playing a card involves putting the card from your hand `in-play` in front of you. During the Discard Phase all `in-play` Ships are discarded, but Bases (and Outposts, which are Bases) remain `in-play`. Therefore Bases Played by any player are `in-play`, even after their turn ends.

Comment: Can you cite sources that prove your answer is correct?

Comment: "In Play" is clearly defined in the rules. I've added the relevant text in hopes of clarifying the meaning of this term and the way that it affects the answer to this question.

Comment: And it works that way in the online implemenation ;)

Comment: I'd have to find the source code to cite that :)

Comment: To be explicit, since you choose to use the abilities of a base in play during your turn... If the stealth tower is not destroyed, on your next turn you can choose a new base to copy?